# Children's short story about kid with reshapeable face

Tags: short-stories, story-identification

I'm looking for a short children's story (or maybe an excerpt of a story) about a kid who realizes his (her?) face is suddenly shapeable like plastic or wax.  That's all I've got.  I remember reading it when I was maybe 9 or 10, back in the very late 70's, early 80's.

Comment: I remember that story. It may have been in Reader's Digest or Highlights. A boy went home from school, discovered his face was mold-able, could not make himself look like he used to. When he went to school the next day, he found that all of his schoolmates had the same ability. I wish I could give you the title but it was so long ago.

Comment: At least I now know that I didn't just make this story up in my own head!  Thanks for the reply - let me know if you ever come across it!

Comment: I stumbled across this today when it randomly popped into my head. I remember the book was a collection of short stories and the cover was a picture of a gnarled old tree. The story of the tree had to do with a witch or something. I'll keep looking.

Answer (score 10):

I found it!  Actually, someone on another site found it. But here it is:  a story called "[The Plastic Age](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?68191)" in an anthology called *[Adrift in Space and Other Stories](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?1624)* published in 1974. An [excerpt mentioned on Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/topic/show/2347586-solved-sci-fi-possibly-part-of-1970s-children-s-digest-series-boy-has#comment_156777488) hints at his ability to mold his face:

> When he awoke, Paul was unaware of the change that had come over him. He was a little groggier than usual, but otherwise, he felt fine. It was only as he began to dress that Paul noticed the change. His skin. Somehow, it was different. It felt smooth and pliable— like the plastic toys that lay scattered about the room.

Thanks to all who helped along the way!

Comment: Please, accept your own answer, ideally adding the matching details.